# How can I animate an opaque material to being fully transparent in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, transparency

I'm working on an animation with Cyscles where I'd like to make a simple face animate between being opaque and completely transparent. How can I do this?

Comment: You could use a transparency shader and a mix shader with an animated factor

Comment: @gandalf3 easy as pie, thank you that's the answer. You might post that answer with a screen shot so people who are newer to Blender than me can get it.

Comment: Yep sorry, I didn't have time at the moment.. Now it looks like @G.Rassovsky answered anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like in the image below.

[image]

Here I have added a simple glass shader to an object and mixed it with a transparent BSDF. Then I simply animate the factor of the mix shader 
(0.0 - 100% Glass / 0% Transparent ; 1.0 - 0% Glass / 100% Transparent).